# MS Access Query - count number of values in a comma separated column

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to count the number of occurrences of values in a comma separated field in a MS Access Table. Any suggestions please :

For example

Table

**ID | Value**

1    |  1,2,3
2    |  1,5,8,9,5
3    |  1,5,8,3

Desired Output

ID   |  # of value

1   |   3
2   |   5
3   |   4

Comment: Will need a custom VBA function that can be called in query or textbox. Develop code and when you encounter specific issue post it for analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *@June7* correctly said, you need a custom function which can be called in your query.

Place this in a Standard Module:

```
Public Function CountValues(ByVal commaValues As Variant) As Long
    If Not IsNull(commaValues) Then CountValues = UBound(Split(commaValues, ",")) + 1
End Function
```

You can now call it in your query:

```
SELECT ID, CountValues(FieldName) AS [# of value]
FROM YourTableName;
```

Output:

ID | [# of value]

1 | 3
 2 | 5
 3 | 4
 4 | 0

NULL values default to zero.

Comment: And I was wrong - VBA is not required for this as shown by another answer but it has flaws.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this with built in functions, without the overhead of calling a custom function:

```
select value,  Len([value])-Len(Replace([value],",","")) as [# of value]
```

Comment: @Gungor , thanks for the answer, but when I use Replace in my query , I am getting the error   , Error: Undefined function 'Replace' in expression.

Comment: that's odd. it may have something to do with your settings, something related to running "unsafe expressions".. what is your environment? windows/office version

Comment: Subtraction returns wrong result. Just use `Len(Replace([value], ",", ""))`. However, if values exceed 9, the result will again be wrong.